# how to restrict direct access from url with any link in browser using struts1.2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hi friends in this scenario i have to restrict direct access with link from url for security purpose, i need same code for this process any one can help me. in this process two users will involved(admin and user).

just i tried this. but not working

```
<security-role><role-name>admin</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>user</role-name></security-role>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>  
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>User</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>  
<http-method>GET</http-method>
<http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>user</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Request processor may help you. Action servlet calls this on every request. And overriding this and having ur own validation for URL may help.

http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#request_processor
http://wiki.apache.org/struts/RequestProcessor

See if this suits your requirement.